# Saving data frequently to SharedPreference/Realm

Tags: android, realm, sharedpreferences

I am getting below error, and possibly ANR due to this while saving data frequently to SharedPreference/Realm

```
08-03 11:19:54.421 4896-5157/? E/SQLiteCastStore: Skip saving device %sV_3acd5341-0779-4e04-a8bf-53e2055046eb
08-03 11:19:54.421 4896-5157/? E/SQLiteCastStore: Skip saving device %sV_b12183ff-3183-4d50-b310-44e8331a9b86
08-03 11:19:54.421 4896-5157/? E/SQLiteCastStore: Skip saving device %sV_b884a63b-5015-45ad-81e5-1a79c154a49a
08-03 11:19:54.421 4896-5157/? E/SQLiteCastStore: Skip saving device %sV_dbd6ac03-45bd-4f6e-ac2d-1f0e6ac88827
08-03 11:19:54.421 4896-5157/? E/SQLiteCastStore: Skip saving device %sV_0f6d5e76-f2c1-4d86-b026-78aeb7c1875f
08-03 11:19:54.421 4896-5157/? E/SQLiteCastStore: Skip saving device %sV_4ff0f920-4cce-45ed-808d-4ed9f13d661d
08-03 11:19:54.421 4896-5157/? E/SQLiteCastStore: Skip saving device %sV_f9f18866-0251-46ea-8013-a87eefe32b74
08-03 11:19:54.421 4896-5157/? E/SQLiteCastStore: Skip saving device %sV_c7dbe775-2799-4d9e-9e5f-a50a1dc907af
08-03 11:19:54.421 4896-5157/? E/SQLiteCastStore: Skip saving device %sV_0ffde9a2-8242-4d8d-a523-b5de8b7c76e8
08-03 11:19:54.421 4896-5157/? E/SQLiteCastStore: Skip saving device %sV_5c2d43dc-a2ab-464e-83ce-a5b7ec8c16b5
08-03 11:19:54.421 4896-5157/? E/SQLiteCastStore: Skip saving device %sV_cd198806-a4d9-46f2-a201-60853f03c6f7
```

**Any pointers? I am totally lost here.**

Comment: not sure how this is related to Realm (the tag `SQLiteCastStore` is not related to it). Need to see the full stack. The only thing I can think of is doing long write transaction on the main thread... To be sure try to setup `StrictMode` https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.html  to detect IO access